# Prove theorem that concerns to sums of exponentials.

Tags: probability-theory, queueing-theory, exponential-sum

I try to solve this theorem:

**Theorem**: Let $x_1, x_2,...$ iid with exponential distribution with rate $\lambda$. The
density function of $S_n$ is given by:
$$
P(S_n \le t)=\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-\lambda t}(\lambda t)^k }{k!},    t\ge 0.
$$

I found one proof is by induction on n, but I'm not sure:

When $n=1$ $S_1$ consider that in a Poisson process, if events occur on average $\lambda t$ occurrences per $t$ units of time. The Poisson distribution describing this process is therefore:

$$P(S_1 \le t)=\frac{e^{-\lambda t}(\lambda t)^1 }{1!}=e^{-\lambda t}\lambda t $$

To do the induction step suppose that the formula is true for n.
$$
P(S_n \le t)=\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-\lambda t}(\lambda t)^k }{k!},    t\ge 0.
$$

So for $n+1$:
$$
P(S_{n+1}<t_2)=P(S_{n}+X_{n+1}<t_2)=P(S_n<t)P(X_{n+1}<t_2-t)
$$
$$
P(S_n<T)P(X_{n+1}<t_2-t)=\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-\lambda t}(\lambda t)^k }{k!}*\frac{e^{-\lambda t}(\lambda t)^{n+1} }{(n+1)!}
$$

$$
\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-\lambda (t+t_2-t)}(\lambda  (t+t_2-t))^k }{k!}=\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-\lambda t_2}(\lambda t_2)^k }{k!}
$$
which completes the proof.

Comment: The easiest way is to link this to a Poisson process. You proof has some flaws in the induction step, $t$ and $T$ appeared there weirdly.

Comment: The expression looks incorrect, when $n = 1$, the correct result should be $P[S_1 \leq t] = 1 - e^{-\lambda t}$, but based on your result, it is $e^{-\lambda t}$. Also, $P[S_n \leq t]$ is not the correct notation for density of $S_n$.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Poisson process theory, the correct expression for $P[S_n \leq t]$ should be given by:
$$P[S_n \leq t] = P[N(t) \geq n] = \sum_{k = n}^\infty e^{-\lambda t} \frac{(\lambda t)^k}{k!}.$$

So maybe what you tried to express is that
$$P[S_n \color{red}{>} t] = 1 - P[S_n \leq t] = \sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1} e^{-\lambda t} \frac{(\lambda t)^k}{k!}.$$

Comment: You are right but this reason I vote-up your answer, thanks. I had noticed my mistake I prepared to amend my mistake and I saw your answer. I found an answer, later I go to post the answer